# How do you make the hidden-field visible?

Tags: html

How do you solve this one line that says hidden-field?

```
<span class="hidden-field"></span>
```

I'm trying to make it visible so it shows on the website.

Comment: It depends on what is making it hidden in the first place. (Not there's much to see since there's no content inside it to be visible).

Answer (score 0):

Add `visibility: visible` and `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to the style of the element.

It might look like this:
`<span class="hidden-field" style="visibility: visible; display: block;"></span>`